# What would a Superconductive Fluid do if drank/inhaled by a human?

Tags: science-based, physics, alternate-reality, superconductors

Hypothetically speaking, if there was a **substance you could drink/inhale** (in an alternate reality) with superconducting properties, how would it influence the brain and the body?

The superconducting fluid, has to be diluted (with a "to be decided" cooling/warming substance) to be drinkable/consumable by humans. Larger quantities would poison you and kill you, since the implanted device I invented wouldn't be able to absorb and synthesise it.

- The **implanted device** makes up for an auxiliary metabolic system to actually break down the fluid.
- The device could act as an electromagnetic controlling system.

What would be negative and positive impacts of a superconductive substance being utilise by a person?

Also feel free to rearrange/change parts of the premises if you find them impossible to fully include in a solution.

Comment: The highest temperature superfluid is a tiny fraction of 1 degree absolute. You want to drink it, and you want a science-based tag. Um...

Answer (score 5):

You don't even need to drink superfluid: you already would become covered in thin film of superfluid both outside and inside a few moments after you opened container holding it. Dependenig on fluid composition it can (optionaly):

- suffocate you - it will cover you lungs inside for sure. If it has large molecules ("not superfluid water") it will prevent breathing.
- poison (or just drug) you - it will get to you bloodstream for sure. If it has small molecules ("superfluid water" )it will get inside all you cells - but it will take several minutes.
- freeze you - when superfluid flows through narrow holes it cools to absolute zero (it "filters out nonsuperfluid fraction"). And you skin and cell walls pours ARE narrow holes.
- dehydrate you - if it is literally superfluid water it can "induce" superfluidness in common water and then it will just spill away through your feet due to gravity.
- dissolve you - if it has highly polar molecules (like HF).
- it can be almost harmless - if it has small enough molecules to allow you to breath, but low enough to not pass you cell barriers. But it will be superslippery - you can fall hard!

Room temperature superfluid is not child toy!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah you are right. Also formulated my question wrongfully. Will either edit or delete and create an entirely different one. Should have just mentioned a substance with superconductivity property and not superfluid state.

Comment: you still has an option to mix this for some plot twist. Like in some conditions (like cold Russian winter) supeconductive fluid becomes also superfluid. And, yes, almost fogot, there can be no supeconductivity in fluids. Supeconductivity needs crystall structure.

Comment: Right. What about though the novel quantum state called "metallic superfluid?"

Comment: https://physicsworld.com/a/metallic-superfluid-seen-in-computer/

Comment: What if for instance, instead, there was a blend of two fluids (not a superfluid) in which one would cool/ warm up the other in order to activate superconductive properties within a temperature the human body can accept? (I know I am stretching this a lot)

Comment: Superfluid can be supeconduct, but normal liquid can't. And real-life superfluids (helium-II at most) are the mix of super and non-super phases. And super-phase has always one and the same constant temperature (exactly absolute zero, actually, but lets handwave it :) ), and all the temperature of the mix comes from non-super pahes. So yes, with some (a lot) handwaving, you may make it plausable: complex molecular liquid, chemicaly inert, about say -20 C (or +20C) temperature of super-phase.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing up superfluidity and superconductivity. The first has electrical neutral particles moving frictionless the other has charge moving frictionless. (To my understanding) Both phenomena can to some degree described similarly. Yet superfluids are special because they are fluids that show no friction and superconductivity is special because it allows electrical charge to move without resistance through its own solid matter.

Concerning your question. I think it might be dangerous to drink something that can easily sneak up through every tiny hole in your body ...potentially interfere or stop bodily functions. Best case scenario it will creep out quickly on your bottom.

Comment: You are correct about the confusion between superconductivity and superfluidity. A superfluid would seep out of a body anywhere, not just out of their bottom.

Comment: Thank you I actually made a mistake there. I meant to use the idea of superconducting properties influencing the body. But superfluid properties are definitely not what I want. I think I will edit the question. Thanks for the funny answer though!